# Comunicação entre Android e dispositivos USB

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para Android que se comunica com um dispositivo USB, uma impressora, um Arduíno ou outro dispositivo Android.

É possível ler e escrever na porta USB do Android? Como devo proceder quanto aos drivers? O Android possui bibliotecas para trabalhar com dispositivos USB? Ouvi falar de um projeto chamado [FTDI Chip](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm) para se comunicar com um dispositivo USB, estou no caminho certo?

Comment: Se você plugar um Android num PC, você pode ler e escrever na memoria interna dele. Além disso o próprio aparelho geralmente permite que você escolha o modo como ele se comunica com o PC. Que dá pra ler e escrever na porta, isso é certo - ela não serve apenas para alimentar o aparelho. Os drivers variam de fabricante para fabricante, mas a API é uma só.

Comment: [Eis a documentação oficial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html). Se alguém quiser elaborar uma resposta sobre isso, seja bem-vindo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existe um projeto no GitHub usb-serial-for-android

É uma library para se comunicar com Arduinos e outros dispositivos via USB no Android, usando o [Android USB Host API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) (Android 3.1+)

Não precisa de acesso ao Root pois implementa os drives no próprio Java, que disponibiliza uma api para o Android receber (read) e enviar (write) na USB.

### Segue o link do projeto: **https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android**

---

Trecho de código, veja mais no projeto de exemplo (https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/tree/master/UsbSerialExamples)

```
// Encontra o UsbManager do Android.
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

// Encontra o primeiro Driver disponivel.
UsbSerialDriver driver = UsbSerialProber.acquire(manager);

if (driver != null) {
  driver.open();
  try {
    driver.setBaudRate(115200);

    byte buffer[] = new byte[16];
    int numBytesRead = driver.read(buffer, 1000);
    Log.d(TAG, "Read " + numBytesRead + " bytes.");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Deal with error.
  } finally {
    driver.close();
  } 
}
```

Nem tudo são flores, pois o projeto ainda estar na versão v0.1.0 e a ultima vez que foi atualizado foi em 2012. Ao menos o projeto estar bem documentado.

Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Comment: Gabriel Santos sua resposta foi muito construtiva vou estudar este projeto, muito obrigado.